# How do I activate a CSS animation on an element by hovering over a different element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-animations

I've found a few different solutions to this but they all rely on one of the elements being inside the other element, and I can't have that in my problem.

I've made a little [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9akLrc5r/8/) that should resemble my problem. When someone hovers "hover me!" I want "move me!" to move toward "hover me!" and also become visible. I've managed to get this to work provided that "hover me!" also moves to the right along with "move me!" but I don't want that to happen, I want "hover me!" to stay in the same spot.

To review, upon hovering "hover me!" I want "move me!" to become visible and move to the right towards "hover me!" on the same line without moving "hover me!" at all.

Help would be much appreciated!

```css
div.txtarea {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}
a.hoverme {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
}
a.moveme {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;  /*THIS IS USUALLY 0 BUT I MADE IT 1 SO WE COULD SEE IT*/
}
a.hoverme:hover > a.moveme {
  -webkit-animation: scrollingIn 1.5s linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes scrollingIn {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0em;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: 1em;
    opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 2em;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="txtarea">
  <a class="moveme" href="#">
        move me!
      </a>
  <a class="hoverme" href="#">
        hover me!
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's the problem haha. Is there any way I could make it more clear what I want?

Comment: I've converted your code block into a snippet. This is not mandatory but I've done it to show you how the snippet works. In the toolbar just click the `<>` button and paste the code in the relevant boxes like you do in Fiddle. This helps in adding a demo directly into the question and thereby avoids extra effort involved in creating a fiddle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In CSS you can affect the properties of one element based on the action on another element only if the element that is used as reference (the one on which the action is performed) is before the element that needs to be styled in the DOM. So, move your `a.moveme` element to be after the `a.hoverme` element and use the `a.hoverme:hover + a.moveme` selector to apply the animation.

The `+` selector is called as adjacent sibling selector and it is used to select the immediate next sibling that follows the reference element (which in our case, is `a.hoverme`).

**Note:** I have changed the initial opacity of the `a.moveme` to 0 so that it becomes visible only when the `a.hoverme` element is hovered on and have also set the `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards` so that the `a.moveme` element stays visible in its final position as long as the hover is on.

I have also included prefix free library in-order to avoid the browser prefixes and to make the snippet viewable in all browsers.

```css
div.txtarea {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}
a.hoverme {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
}
a.moveme {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
}
a.hoverme:hover + a.moveme {
  animation: scrollingIn 1.5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes scrollingIn {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0em;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: 1em;
    opacity: .5;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 2em;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="txtarea">
  <a class="hoverme" href="#">
    hover me!
  </a>
  <a class="moveme" href="#">
    move me!
  </a>
</div>
```

---

For this particular effect, you don't even need animations. This can be achieved using transitions also like in the below snippet. Defining the `transition` property within the `a.hoverme:hover + a.moveme` selector would mean that the transition happens only while hovering in and not while hovering out. On hover out, the element simply disappears. I've done this to mimick the output produced by animations.

```css
div.txtarea {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}
a.hoverme {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
}
a.moveme {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
}
a.hoverme:hover + a.moveme {
  margin-left: 2em;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="txtarea">
  <a class="hoverme" href="#">
    hover me!
  </a>
  <a class="moveme" href="#">
    move me!
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, okay, so you're saying that there is no way to move it if it's on the left of the "hover me"? Is there any way with Javascript or something? thanks a ton for your time.

Comment: @Egrodo: No, on the page we can make it appear on the left of hover me but in HTML the element cannot appear before hover me. I am accessing through phone right now. Will add a sample of what I mean in the morning. It should be possible with just CSS.

Comment: I added an answer so I could update Harry's snippet to have the 'hover me' on the right - as he already said, you can position it (float, position, margin, padding, etc.) however you want, it just has to preceed the 'move me' element in the html document order.  my update simply changes float:left to float:right to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

@Harry 's snippet with a very slight tweak:

```css
div.txtarea {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}
a.hoverme {
  float: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
}
a.moveme {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
}
a.hoverme:hover + a.moveme {
  margin-left: 2em;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="txtarea">
  <a class="hoverme" href="#">
    hover me!
  </a>
  <a class="moveme" href="#">
    move me!
  </a>
</div>
```

If you want the 'hover me' on the right, you just have to change it to `float:right` instead of `float:left.`