# CSS Transition not triggering on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` rectangle that's supposed to transition when I hover over another element. However, it does not do that. I found out about how one can transition/animate an element when hovering over another when looking at [a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961719/how-do-i-activate-a-css-animation-on-an-element-by-hovering-over-a-different-ele). Please help!

```css
div.invis_container {
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.image {
    width: 750px;
    height: 750px;
    position: absolute;
}

.bar {
    background-color: rgb(0, 37, 107);
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

.image:hover + .bar {
    height: 200px;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class=invis_container>
    <img src="assets/paint_green_blue.png" class=image>
    <img src="assets/island.png" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; opacity: 0.3; position: absolute;
    top: 150px; left: 350px;">
    <div class=bar></div>
    <h3 style="font-size: 40px; width: 1000px; position: absolute; top: 400px; left: 400px;">
        Test text
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: I've put the code in a snippet, but I guess you can edit it to improve.

Comment: Trying putting transition on .bar, not image:hover .bar

Comment: @SteveTomlin
It does work if I put it into .bar, but I want to transition the element when I hover over .image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator):

> The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and
> matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first
> element, and both are children of the same parent element.

So this selector is not working here. You can change the markup order and put `.bar` **immediately** after `.image` OR use another selector like [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).

Answer (score 0):

The (+) selector is used for adjacent selection so you should have your .bar element immediately after the .image element.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class=invis_container>
    <img src="assets/paint_green_blue.png" class=image>
    <div class=bar></div>
    <img src="assets/island.png" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; opacity: 0.3; position: absolute;
top: 150px; left: 350px;">
    <h3 style="font-size: 40px; width: 1000px; position: absolute; top: 400px; left: 400px;">
    Test text
    </h3>
</div>
```